# ViewModel Not Being Recognized by MVC 6 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

I created a ViewModel called AddNewInventoryViewModel (Project is ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio Code on OSX with the runtime .NET Core 5.0) and added it into the ViewModel models folder, so that I have the structure:

```
ViewModels/Home/AddNewInventoryViewModel.cs
Views/Home/AddNewInventory.cshtml
```

My view looked like this:

```
@model AddNewInventoryViewModel
...Content here
```

My Home controller action method looked like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddNewInventory()
{
    return View();    
}
```

For sake of brevity, I won't include the ViewModel.cs file itself.

However, when I visited the page in my app (AddNewInventory.cshtml), I received the error:

```
DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace 
'AddNewInventoryViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why the error? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error is that I failed to add a reference in the _ViewImports.cshtml in the Views folder. For example, below I was missing the project.ViewModels.Home reference.

```
@using project
@using project.Models
@using project.ViewModels.Account
@using project.ViewModels.Manage
@using project.ViewModels.Home
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

One I added that, everything worked fine.